# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Users at 0x1b9b3dd59d0>' is already attached to session '5' (this is '6')

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to update data in database (PostgreSQL), and when i try updating or deleting a row i get this error **sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Users at 0x1b9b3dd59d0>' is already attached to session '5' (this is '6')**

```
# Update user
@app.route('/users/<id_user>', methods = ['PUT'])
def updateUser(id_user):
    user = Users.query.get_or_404(id_user)
    
    data = request.get_json()
    user.name = data['name']
    user.phone = data['phone']
    user.role = data['role']
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

    return {"message": f"user updated."}
```

```
# Delete user
@app.route('/users/<id_user>', methods = ['Delete'])
def deleteUser(id_user):
    user = Users.query.get_or_404(id_user)
    db.session.delete(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return {"message": f"user deleted."}
```

Comment: try using merge instead of add. for the first case. as for delete I am not sure why that is happening.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the help i was able to fix the problem of the update. I'm still confused why delete doesn't work.